# Logitech K800 keyboard has non-functioning keys

Tags: usb, keyboard, logitech, wireless-keyboards

Hmmm, this seems to have fixed itself overnight. Strange!
As you were...

I recently bought a new Logitech K800 keyboard (wireless, illumiated), paired it to the unified receiver I am already using for my mouse (using solaar), and discovered that the 'd', 'TAB' and left 'ALT' keys were not working.

The keyboard works on the same system when booted into Windows 7, and I can unpair it and connect it via a different unified receiver to my laptop and it works fine.

Both the laptop and this system are running Ubuntu 15.04.

Additionally, if I boot this system into Ubuntu 15.04 from a bootable USB stick the keyboard works fine.

So I'm concluding that there's something left over from earlier upgrades (I can't remember the first version of Ubuntu I installed on this machine!) that's causing the non-functioning key problem. I've tried comparing files in /etc/ with those on the laptop but haven't found anything that changes the behaviour.

Incidently, I have an older logitech wired USB keyboard connected at the same time and it works properly.

Any clues for places to check re old files or configurations would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with my k800 keyboard today. My <kbd>i</kbd> key wasn't working.

I disassembled the keyboard to discover that there was a lot of dirt and dust in it. I also noticed that under the key tab there's a little soft part that make a contact while pressed.  Under this soft transparent rubber part there a little electrical contact and it was dirty.

So I removed the two little white brackets clipped under the key cap around the soft rubber part. I de-clipped them gently. Then I cleaned the area of the key with a small child's paintbrush and my vacuum hose close to it to remove the dust. Then I use 99% isopropyl alcohol and the little paintbrush to clean the electrical contact under the rubber part. I also put some more alcohol over the soft rubber part and pressed it several times. After that I reassembled the keyboard and the <kbd>i</kbd> key was fixed.